spinnaker deployment through helm in minikube
while deploying the chart i am getting an error
WARNING: This chart is deprecated
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: spinnaker/charts/minio/templates/deployment.yaml:210:20: executing "spinnaker/charts/minio/templates/deployment.yaml" 
at <(not .Values.gcsgateway.enabled) (not .Values.azuregateway.enabled) (not .Values.s3gateway.enabled) (not .Values.b2gateway.enabled)>: can't give argument to non-function not .Values.gcsgateway.enabled

and when am doing minio equal to false then it is running but not all pod is creating
I want to deploy spinnaker with all components in minikube

Not sure what helm chart you are using but stable/spinnaker chart has been deprecated.
You can use https://github.com/OpsMx/spinnaker-helm instead. There is some issue with default versions but you can override them
values.yaml
halyard:
  spinnakerVersion: 1.33.0
  image:
    tag: 1.51.0

helm repo add spinnaker https://opsmx.github.io/spinnaker-helm/
helm repo update

kubectl create namespace spin
helm install oss-spin spinnaker/spinnaker -n spin --timeout 1000s -f values.yaml

Note: make sure you have enough resources on your minikube
